# How can i make NSMenu not disappear When i click it's menuItem's subMenu

Tags: cocoa, events, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nspopover

I custom a NSMenu, i set the NSMenuItem's Action, which is it will show a NSPopover when i click the NSMenuItem. i need to do something on NSPopover, But the NSMenu will disappear when i click the NSPopover, what should i do to make the NSPopover exist till i finish the things on NSPopover, In other words, How can i control the NSMenu's disappear event. Who can give me some advice? thank you!

Here is some code:

```
NSMenuItem *deadTimeLineItem = [[NSMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]] initWithTitle:@"" action:@selector(showCalendarAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[self setAutoenablesItems:NO];
[deadTimeLineItem setTarget:self];
TaskDeadTimeLineView *deadTimeLineView = [[TaskDeadTimeLineView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 40)];
[deadTimeLineItem setView:deadTimeLineView];
[self addItem:deadTimeLineItem];

//Action
- (void)showCalendarAction:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    if (self.menuDelegate && [self.menuDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showCalendarViewWith:)]) {
        [self.menuDelegate showCalendarViewWith:item];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a popover. Use a submenu or a dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I try your method. It works.